# Proof of this rule used in comparison tests : $ln(n)\leq\frac{n^\alpha}{\alpha}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

In comparison test , there is a rule that is used a lot :
$$\ln(n) \leq \frac{n^\alpha}{\alpha}$$
**I would like to know what is the proof of this rule??**

I will give an example of how it is used :

if we want to check the convergence of
$$\sum\frac{\ln(n)}{n^{3/2}}$$ 
we may assume that alpha=0.1 
hence
$$\ln(n) \leq \frac{n^{0.1}}{0.1}$$
$$\frac{\ln(n)}{n^{3/2}} \leq \frac{1}{0.1\  n^{1.4}}$$
since$$\sum\frac{1}{n^{1.4}}$$ converges , then 
$$\sum\frac{\ln(n)}{n^{3/2}}$$ 
converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from $\log x ≤ x$. Plugging in $x=n^\alpha$ immediately gives $\alpha \log n ≤ n^\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Write $\log n=\frac1\alpha\log(n^\alpha)$ and use $\log x\le x$.